# Salesforce remove NameSpace Prefix

Tags: salesforce-classic

Can we remove namespace prefix in salesforce? Because I have not seen any option  available there in salesforce

Comment: Why are you looking to remove the namespace prefix? Is this in a developer org?

Comment: Yes It is in developer org

Comment: I want to remove because everywhere in the org while creating field in standard or custom objects the api name of field comes up with the long name of namespace prefix

Comment: you can't remove namespace prefix. signup for another dev org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a namespace prefix is created, it cannot be changed or deleted. The workaround is to move all your code to a new Developer Organization, where you can setup the desired Namespace Prefix.

Please refer to the Product Manager's post on the Community Board: [How to change the namespace after package creation?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008vSKIAY)

Please refer to the IdeaExchange post for a suggested change to the behavior of this feature: [Cannot remove/edit Namespace prefix, once defined for Managed Apps](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqjiAAC)

[image]

Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000060519&type=1